# Avoid repetitive calls to a Routine from Multiple Threads within a win form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I have a Private object variable within a Windows form which has performs the tcp/IP socket connection and keeps the connection opened.

On form_load this object is initialized and the form has 15-20 Threads running continously within it which access this object. There are scenarios where in which the Tcp/Ip connection might be lost. SO whenever i find that the connection is lost i call the **ReconnectToSocket()** Method within the thread. I am performing the below code to ensure that the **ReconnectToSocket()** method is only called once by using **_ReconnectingSocket** property. But after checking the Text Log files i found out that this method is called within each sub thread's.

**How can i make sure that this method is called only once and avoid repetitive calls.**

Below is my code. I am interested in any alternative approach, because i feel that this is not the right approach in doing so.

```
    bool _bReconnectingSocket = false;//To check if it is currently reconnecting
    readonly object lock_reconnectSocket = new object();
    private bool _ReconnectingSocket
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lock_reconnectSocket)
            {
                return this._bReconnectingSocket;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (lock_reconnectSocket)
            {
                this._bReconnectingSocket = value;
            }
        }
    }


    private void ReconnectToSocket()
    {
        if (!this._ReconnectingSocket)
        {
            this._ReconnectingSocket = true;

            //Each sub thread checks for this variable while looping and exits from the infinite loop
            this._Stop = true;

            //Join all the Sub Threads Before Reconnecting
            foreach (SocketThread thrd in this._subThreadCol)
            {
                try
                {
                    this._objLog.WriteInfo(string.Format("Joining Subthread - {0} for Reconnecting.", thrd.ThrdID));
                    thrd.Join();
                }
                catch { }
            }

            this.ConnectSocket();

            this._ReconnectingSocket = false;
            this._Stop = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks very fishy.  You cannot hide the fact that the connection was lost to a thread that was actively transferring data.  The transfer can't complete, it must be restarted.  Some mishaps are just too impactful to work around.  Using 15 threads doesn't make much sense here.  Threads buy you more cpu cycles, it doesn't make the machine on the other end of the wire faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write something like that in your class. Your routine still might be called several times, but its actual body will be executed only once at a time, if `reconnected` field is false.

```
bool reconnected = false;
object lockObject = new object();

void ReconnectToSocket()
{
  lock(lockObject)
  {
    if(!reconnected) { /*do stuff*/; reconnected = true; }
  }
}
```

Comment: If is use a lock, and in a scenario where in which 5 thread calls the routine ReconnectToSocket() at the same time and 1st one acquires the Lock and then the remaning 4 waits for it. As soon as the first one completes, then second one would acquire and perform the same task again. I want to avoid this.

Comment: You're right, all threads will acquire a lock eventually, but they will release it without performing any tasks because of `if(!reconnected)` condition.

Comment: let me get this approach implemented and test out.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the object you lock against should be static private of the class and not an instance member. One thing I am not sure about is why you are sharing same connection among threads instead of having each thread to open, consume and immediately close its own one like we would do with a SqlConnection.

Comment: I need to persist the connection throught out. Every 5-10 seconds messages and instruction are passed using the connection. So i dont want to open & close connection and neither keep different objects for each thread.